# How do I get the currently registered channel in notify_run, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, notify

I am using `notify_run` module to create a new channel, followed by using it to push notifications. I am successful in crating channel from within the code and using it as well. But, I would like to get the details of the channel registered/currently in use. I have tried to store the output from command prompt, and use that later.

```
notify = Notify()
k = str(notify.register())
l = str(k.split('\n')[0])
channel_link = l.split(': ')[1]
```

I would like to know is there is any other method to do so. The [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/notify-run/) does not specify much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're parsing the response for the endpoint URL, if that's the case you can do the following to get it..

```
notify = Notify()
channel = notify.register()
endpoint = channel.endpoint
print(endpoint) # https://notify.run/<channel_code>
```

You can also get the channel_page, which is a page that has the channel info, QR code, and link to subscribe.

```
channel_page = channel.channel_page
print(channel_page) # https://notify.run/c/<channel_page_code>
```